# Set Div TOP position as percentage of browser width (define height position by width)

Tags: css, html, position, width, percentage

I am assuming I will need Javascript for this, but perhaps there is a CSS trick I'm not aware of.

I have a web page based on a square background image. Ideally, the user would always set the browser as a square, but I know that won't happen.

Because the image is square, if the image is set to fill the browser at 100%, the width is always the same as where the "bottom" of the page should be.

Thus, to position an element dynamically horizontally (so the page can be resized but still hold it's structure), the top position of said element is a percentage of the width.

In other words, if I have a horizontal bar that should ALWAYS be positioned 85% from the top of the image, the top position can be defined as 85% of width (top:85% [of browser width]).  If you simply define the top of the horizontal bar as 85% (top:85%;), the horizontal bar's position will vary with the height of the browser window (whereas if you set it as 85% of the width it would be exactly where I want it).

As mentioned before, this is likely an easy thing to do with Javascript, but I don't know Javascript.  I assume there isn't a function in CSS that will allow positioning by calculating a percentage of width, but that would be ideal.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

======================================

[image]
<sub>(source: [renboy.com](http://renboy.com/images/squareWeb.jpg))</sub>

Unfortunately I'm a new user and the interface won't allow me to post a photo.

The page is square (a large, square image).  There is a horizontal navbar who's top should be positioned 85% from the top of the image (it would be defined as (top:85%;) if the browser were opened to the exact same size and dimension (square) of the image).

However, if someone drags the bottom of their browser down (to make a tall rectangle), 85% will not be where I want it over the image.  HOWEVER, 85% of the width will ALWAYS be in the exact right spot (because the image always fills 100% of the width).  So, if I could define the horizontal position as 85% of the browser *width* (instead of height), the navbar would be exactly where I want it, no matter what dimensions the browser is open to.  Thanks in advance for any possible solutions.

==================
Doing more research, it would seem that the answer might lie in Jquery (using position or maybe outerWidth or possibly something like var winWidth = $(window).width();), but I have no experience with Java/Javascript.  Any help out there?  Again, I want to set the position of the div holding the horizontal navigation bar to 85% of the width of the browser window. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to change all your java references to javascript.  They're different things completely.

Comment: java != javascript. Java runs as an applet, javascript runs in the browser.

Comment: ^ and only one of them makes me break out in hives.

Comment: It might be worth providing an image to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve. Your description is a little hard to follow.

Comment: As mentioned... I don't really know Java... script. (evidently I don't even know what it's called)

Comment: @DavidThomas: I'm not sure it will help with the explanation, but I'll upload it somewhere so someone can grab it.  Thanks. http://renboy.com/images/squareWeb.jpg

Comment: You want a background image that takes up the full screen and you want a bar to always stay a few pixels away from the bottom?

Comment: @Cleverbot: Nope.  That would just be a sticky footer.  I want to be able to position a horizontal navbar at the same place over the image, even though the image size is dynamic (resizes to fill the browser window). I know how to make the image fill the browser window, it's the position of the horizontal nav bar that's tricky (because the placement is dynamic and needs to be based on the browser width, instead of the height --which is what's normally done).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/f7RMA/

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://renboy.com/images/squareWeb.jpg">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.box img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.box .bar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 85%;
}
```

WTF happens: `.box` is set to 100% width. The image inside is also set to 100%. Images in non-crappy browsers keep their aspect ratio when they are resized by only one side. `.box` wants contain the image entirely, so its height will be set to image's height. Because `.box` is positioned absolute, you can put the `.bar` inside the `.box` and position it vertically as you wish, because `.box` now has a well-defined height.

Comment: Beautiful! --in that it works on its own.  However, now any image inside "box" will want to be 100%. Thus, the images placed inside the navbar (or any other div inside "box") won't show.

Any good idea of a way to get around this problem?  Sorry if this is a dumb question, but is there a command to prevent the parent command of .box img {width:100%;} from altering images in other div's inside that parent div (can you clear the .box img stuff in a child div)?

Comment: You are my hero.  Thanks SO much.