# Positioning an image in CSS using px giving different results based on monitor resolution

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am very new to coding in html and css and would like to know a way to get around my problem of positioning an image using pixels. The snippet of code looks like:

```
#contact .map .box_wrapp{
position: absolute;
left: 670px;
margin: 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.4);
padding: 33px 0 33px;
background: white;
top: 41%;
border-radius: 25px;
}
```

When viewing the page on different screens "670px" is a different distance and it ends up overlapping another image on the same page. How can I either position it relative to the other image or possibly position it using something like device pixels? (I started out programming android apps so the concept of device pixels is familiar to me).

Comment: absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element who is not  statically positioned. the code you showed is not enough to make a conclusive answer but my guess is the parent element of these element is not a fixed width, also the other image you're talking about is not absolutely position like these elements. if you're not familiar with positioning you should read about them as they are a major cause of gotchas for those who don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query and define different style for each monitor.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

This section will apply on monitor up to 300px width, set couple of this according to your supported devices

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {
{
#contact .map .box_wrapp{
left: 670px;
margin: 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.4);
padding: 33px 0 33px;
background: white;
top: 41%;
border-radius: 25px;
}
```

}

But better way for you is to set width using percentage and not pixels

Comment: Wait, can I set the image to be positioned something like 75% the length of the screen? So that it appears somewhat scaled on every screen? I'm not talking about the size of the image but the position of it

Comment: Yes,  see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478163/set-div-top-position-as-percentage-of-browser-width-define-height-position-by-w

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using css @media rule, this is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices.

e.g 

@media only screen and (max-width: 670px) {
    #contact .map .box_wrapp{ {
        //some style
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 350px) {
    #contact .map .box_wrapp{ {
        //some style
    }
}
```